# gitlab-runner config.toml file unchanged after registering?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

In order to test CI/CD pipeline in my Windows 10 using Docker, I tried installing and registering `gitlab-runner`by following the instruction in 
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html

However, because the file `config.toml` is in different location and `docker.sock` cannot be found in windows, I tried to install it using the following command instead:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner-config -v /gitlab-runner busybox:latest /bin/true
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
--volumes-from gitlab-runner-config \
gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

I also successfully registered gitlab-runner using docker, and I chose `docker`as the executor and `alpine:latest` as default image.

```
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

Even so, when I checked `config.toml` in my `Gitlab-Runner` folder, it didn't update with any new information:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
```

May I ask is there any problems in regard to the `config.toml` right after the register process? Or do I need to do anything after this?

My `config.toml` location:

```
C:\Program Files
--Gitlab-Runner
 |--config.toml
 |--gitlab-runner.exe
```

**docker container ls**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
612ddafde46f        gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes                           gitlab-runner
```

Comment: Can you post your docker register command? The default register command from the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker) uses `-v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner`, and so the `config.yml` file would be stored in `/srv/gitlab-runner/config/config.toml`. So I have some speculation that the `config.toml` file you have would be located in `/gitlab-runner`.